# Is $\dim \text{Im }T \leq \dim V$ in infinite dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a linear map $T: V \to W$ between finite-dimensional vector spaces, we have $\dim \text{Im }T \leq \dim V$. Is there an analog for infinite dimensions?

Comment: What do mean by $dim(V)$ when $V$ is an infinite dimensional space. Do u mean $dim(V)=|Basis(V)|$ ? If so then the answer posted already is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact same inequality holds for infinite dimensional space and for the same reason: the image of a linear space under a linear map is spanned by the image of a basis of $V$.